# How can set bootstrap glyphicon to html input type button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm new in bootstrap ,want to create simple button with glyphicon icon,for that purpose write this html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> سبد خرید شما &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge"> @ViewBag.BAGCOUNT</span>
</button>
```

every thing is good but want to when button fire go to on of controller action method means change to this code:

```
    <input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "User")'"/>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> سبد خرید شما &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge"> @ViewBag.BAGCOUNT</span>
```

but that code show me this:
[image]

How can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: Why change from the `<button>`?. Just handle the buttons `.click()` event.

Comment: Or better, replace `<button>` with `<a>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes,for just button click

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you write me how can ise <a>?

Comment: `<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "User")" class="btn btn-success" ><span class="glyphicon .....</span></a>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks that's work,please post your code ,can vote up you my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to change the `<button>` to an `<input>` element. You could simply handle the `onclick` event of the `<button>`, however it would be easier to just use a link

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "User")" class="btn btn-success" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> سبد خرید شما &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="badge"> @ViewBag.BAGCOUNT</span>
</a>
```